# Give Input to AJAX Calendar by using EXCEL VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I have a requirement where I am trying to give input to a drop down box that in turn gets the input from an AJAX Calendar in the website. Here, the drop down only accepts the data from the AJAX Calendar. Hence is there a way I can choose the required date in the AJAX Calendar by using Excel VBA? How can I pass the input to the AJAX calendar so that that particular date can be picked(clicked)?

Comment: You should add the values you need to pass as an appropriate query string parameters within the GET request URL.

Comment: Is that dropown created using HTML select option tag? If yes than there is a possibility to select the value using VBA code. You can try to post your sample HTML code for that drop down. We can try to suggest VBA code sample for it.

Comment: The options for the drop down are limited (i.e) it only lists few dates of the year, if we want to pick other dates the input is only being accepted from the calendar. I did a workaround and automated the usual manual way how we pick dates. (ie navigate until find the year , then find the month , then find the date and GetElementbyID.Click.) Sorry could not share code as internal.Thanks for your comments i am working to find much quicker ways.